# different versions of the shared library

Tags: dynamic-linking

I have a `-lelf` option in my makefile, I want to know: how does it choose the version of `libelf.so` to link (e.g. `libelf.so.0` or `libelf.so.1`)? I do have a `libelf.so.1` in my system, as well as a `libelf.so` which links to `libelf.so.1`. When I compile the code, everything is fine, however, when I try to run the binary, it reports: "can not find libelf.so.0". Any guide on solving this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I understand something. I can specify which version of the .so at compile-time (I can force it to link to libelf.so.1, while it will cause some problem at run-time). It seems the best way is to find the required libelf.so.0 anyhow.